# How To create dynamic List ul and li based on data from database

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to create a small notification feature in my personal project, I'm using **JSF**, **Primefaces** as technologies, and i would like to make the **ul** and **li** dynamically behaving based on the size od data retrieved from database, like **github** or **stackoverflow** or **facebook** does.

I hope you guys can give a clue solution, suggestion, a tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [ask]. This seems off topic for SO. Damn, can't find the shortcut for this page ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<p:repeat>`, see this [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/repeat.xhtml) to adapt the component to your need. or you can use `<ui:repeat>`, see this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-repeat-tag-example/).

Comment: I'm using primfecaes **5.1**, unfortunately this feature doesn't exist in that version.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request, you can integrate ui:repeat into a p:dataScroller.
See http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datascroller/inline.xhtml